# Does raising a parentclass exception ensure that a child class exception will be called

Tags: python-3.x, exception

```
1    except (ValidationError, TicketValidationError) as exception_error_1:
2        raise ValidationError from exception_error_1
```

TicketValidationError inherits from ValidationError.
My question is if it's a TicketValidationError will line 2 still be called?

Comment: Yes, and you only need to write `except ValidationError`. Which raises the question why you need to write this at all.

Comment: not code I wrote. I was wrestling with pylint and just making sure.